# Setting the selectedindex property of an HTML dropdown using PHP

Tags: php

From the database I pull back the user information and based on this I can determine the correct index value using a case statement:

```
<?php
    $genderIndex = 0;
    switch ($displayProperties['gender']) 
    {
        case "":
            $genderIndex = 0;
            break;
        case "Male":
            $genderIndex = 1;
            break;
        case "Female":
            $genderIndex = 2;
            break;
        case "Other":
            $genderIndex = 3;
            break;
    }
 ?>
```

On the form I have an HTML dropdown (select):

```
<select name="gender" selectedIndex="<?php echo $genderIndex; ?>">
    <option value="0"> </option>
    <option value="Male">Male</option>
    <option value="Female">Female</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select><br/>
```

The problem is it never works and always loads the page at `index=0` and I made sure to verify if `$genderIndex` actually has the expected value (it does).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

selectedindex property is not used in this way, for  appropriate use of the selectedindex property you can view http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_selectedindex.asp.

Instead what you are after is applying the "selected" attribute to the appropriate option. The code below runs some shorthand if/else checks and will apply the "selected" attribute where appropriate, based on your $genderIndex you created in your function given.

```
<select name="gender">
    <option value="0" <?php echo ($genderIndex==0)?('selected'):(''); ?>"> </option>
    <option value="Male" <?php echo ($genderIndex==1)?('selected'):(''); ?>>Male</option>
    <option value="Female" <?php echo ($genderIndex==2)?('selected'):(''); ?>>Female</option>
    <option value="Other" <?php echo ($genderIndex==3)?('selected'):(''); ?>>Other</option>
</select><br/>
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks. I'm using CodeLobster and the autocomplete had the SelectedIndex property so I thought I had to use that. I guess that property either doesn't work or CodeLobster should not be suggesting it for that <select> tag.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is not working is because *selectedIndex* is not a valid attribute on the HTML `<select/>` element. (See http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.6)

To pre-select an option in the `<select/>` element (other than the first one, in this an empty value), you need to have your HTML output look something like this:

```
<select name="gender">
<option value="0"> </option>
<option value="Male">Male</option>
<option value="Female" selected="true">Female</option>
<option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
```

Notice the addition of the *selected="true"* on the second `<option/>` tag. Something like the following will get the job done but is hardly elegant.

```
<select name="gender">
<?php
if(0 == $genderIndex)
    echo '<option value="0" selected="true"> </option>';
else
    echo '<option value="0"> </option>';

if(1 == $genderIndex)
    echo '<option value="Male" selected="true">Male</option>';
else
    echo '<option value="Male">Male</option>';

if(2 == $genderIndex)
    echo '<option value="Female" selected="true">Female</option>';
else
    echo '<option value="Female">Female</option>';

if(3 == $genderIndex)
    echo '<option value="Other" selected="true">Other</option>';
else
    echo '<option value="Other">Other</option>';
?>
</select>
```

A good web framework can be helpful here. I know that in Java, the Struts framework assists with echoing a `<select/>` tag to the output with the appropriate `<option/>` selected.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you specify the selected `<option>` in HTML. You need to have the `selected` attribute on the `<option>` itself, like so:

```
<select name="gender">
    <option value="0"> </option>
    <option value="Male" selected>Male</option>
    <option value="Female">Female</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select><br/>
```